Export variable in Makefile with ifeq, then access variable elsewhere
Within a Makefile, I am trying to export a variable conditionally using an ifeq block, and then access that variable in a second ifeq block. Here's a sample of my code structure:
ifeq ($(CONDITION),true)
    export RESULT=$$(echo $$ENV_VAR) ; \ 
    echo "$$RESULT" ;
else
    export RESULT=$$(echo $$ENV_VAR_2) ; \
    echo "$$RESULT" ;
endif
ifeq ($CONDITION2),true)
    echo "$$RESULT" ;
endif

In the code above, the first two echo statements (lines 3 and 6) print out correctly, but the third echo (line 9) does not print any output, even when CONDITION2 evaluates to true. I've tried several different tests and format/syntax, but I can't figure out how to get the  third echo statement on line 9 to evaluate to print out the value set in the first ifeq block.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

The above is not, by itself, legal makefile content.  So, it must be part of a larger context and without seeing that full context we can't be sure of the answer.
However, most likely you have overlooked the fact that (by default) every line in a makefile is invoked in a separate shell.  Thus, shell variables that are set on one line of a recipe will have no effect on the next line.  That's why you need the backslash.
In general I strongly discourage anyone from adding conditional statements (ifeq etc.) into the middle of recipes.  It's very confusing and hard to read and work with.
There are many ways to resolve this issue, but most of them depend on the actual behavior you are using; I doubt the example you provide is very representative of the real makefile you're working with.
Without knowing the real thing you want to do all I can suggest is setting a make variable to the "second" command then using that variable in the recipe, like this:
ifeq ($(CONDITION2),true)
  SECOND_CMD = echo "$$RESULT"
endif

target: ...
ifeq ($(CONDITION),true)
         export RESULT=$$(echo $$ENV_VAR) ; \ 
         echo "$$RESULT" ; \
         $(SECOND_CMD)
else
         export RESULT=$$(echo $$ENV_VAR_2) ; \
         echo "$$RESULT" ; \
         $(SECOND_CMD)
endif

but there are likely cleaner ways to do it.

Thanks so much for the reply! That makes sense based on your comment that each makefile line is run by a different shell. Do you know of a good way I could instead just use a non-export variable, and set the variable depending on the first condition? And then the second ifeq block could access the variable? Sorry if this is a simple question, I'm still working on getting more familiar with Makefiles.

I still don't understand what you really need to do.  One option is to set the variable name in a condition outside the rule, like ifeq ... / VARNAME = ENV_VAR / else / VARNAME = ENV_VAR_2 / endif then you could reference it like RESULT=$$$(VARNAME) from within the recipe.  But I have no idea if that can actually work for you in the real makefile you're trying to write.

Thanks a lot for sending that suggestion! I mostly just needed to confirm if that logic/syntax in my post should work, or if there was a clear better alternative to that scenario, and your answers have definitely helped clear it up. Sorry I'm not able to post the whole code, it's just proprietary so I'm not able to post the whole thing publicly. Thank you again for your helpful ideas!!

We don't need to/want to see "the whole code"; that would be too much.  It's just helpful if the sample code posted is close enough to the real code, that solutions we provide are  relevant to the real problem rather than based on false assumptions suggested by a partial example.  Glad you got it worked out!
